# Java Period Conversion dates to float

Tags: java

I have day of birth and second LocalDate.now()
I use Periof for print this

```
            Period test = Period.between(dateofbirth,LocalDate.now());
```

but if i want print this error "P5Y8M11D"

what can i do to get it-  "You live in the world 10,23 years"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [`Period#getYears`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#getYears--)

`P5Y8M11D` is the default format of [`Period#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#toString--). You can get the components of period e.g. years, months, days etc. from the object of `Period` as per your requirement using its corresponding accessor methods.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate dateofbirth = LocalDate.of(1975, 7, 15);
        Period test = Period.between(dateofbirth, LocalDate.now());
        System.out.printf("You have lived in the world for %d years.%n", test.getYears());

        double years = test.getYears() + test.getMonths() / 12.0 + test.getDays() / 365.0;
        System.out.printf("You have lived in the world for %.2f years.%n", years);

        DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
        format.applyPattern("#,##0.00");
        String formattedValue = format.format(years);
        System.out.printf("You have lived in the world for %s years.%n", formattedValue);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
You have lived in the world for 45 years.
You have lived in the world for 45.36 years.
You have lived in the world for 45,36 years.
```

Comment: yeee, but i want print

Output:
You live in the world 10,23 years"
i must sum all days, all months and all years ?

Comment: @WiceJav - I've updated the answer based on your clarification. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the epoch format to get secondes and compare them :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate dateofbirth = LocalDate.of(1975, 7, 15);
    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 - dateofbirth.atStartOfDay().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.printf("You have lived in the world for %f years.%n", new Float(duration) / 3600 / 24 / 365);
}
```